# Powershell post/get from PHP script

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have used the following code in Excel VBA before now which posts a variable to a PHP script on my website and gets a returned value:

```
<script>
myURL = "http://www.example.com/Scripts/myscript.php?password=password"
winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-    urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send
msgbox winHttpReq.responseText
</script>
```

I want to do something similar in Powershell instead but cannot find anything?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!

```
$r = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.example.com/Scripts/myscript.php?password=password")
$resp = $r.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
write-host $result
```